# SailsJS + Waterline + MongoDB - Should I stop using?

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo, nosql

I am concerned that SailsJS + Waterline + MongoDB is not a winning combination anymore. Our application is using "Waterline Associations" more and more and I find its functionality is limiting my application.

I want to find by association, which does not seem possible. I can only populate with subcriterias, but that does not help as it does not exclude the entries that does not match the subcritera.

E.g:

```
Document.find({type: 'pdf'}).populate('owners', {where: { name: 'contains' : XYZ }).exec(...
```

The result from the above query gives me ALL documents with type: pdf. That is NOT what I need. Any good way to solve this?

Also case-insensitive queries seems impossible?

So ... should I start looking towards something else? or am I missing something completely?

Answer (score 0):

We are using sails.js, Waterline and MongoDB for almost 2 years in production.
The association part is really not well suited and we will develop something for the associations (especially many-to-many) on top of Waterline on our own.

To your questions:

- I propose to flip the 2 models:

`Owner.find({ name: 'contains' : XYZ }).populate('documents', {where: {type: 'pdf'}).exec(...`

- You can do wlNext: { caseSensitive: true//false } in the adapter. See [this issue](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/239)